# How to improve Rxjs statement?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have the following Rxjs statement:

```
    const versionsRequest2$ = (num: string) =>
        request2$(num).pipe(
            map((versions) => {
                const p = new P();
                p.setVersions(versions);
                return p;
            }),
        );
```

How to improve `map()` statement? I dislike, I have tried to create instance of class and fill it by data from response.

I can improve this using:

```
map((versions) =>  new P().setVersions(versions)),
```

If constructor `P` and `setVersions` returns `this` inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a constructor for `P` that accepts a `versions` argument. Then you can just do:

```
const versionsRequest2$ = (num: string) =>
  request2$(num).pipe(
    map((versions) => new P(versions)),
  );
```

Comment: What if I should pass concrete type of versions? I have class model: `class Version {}` with properties inside. And I need to convers JSON response to this class model and assign to `P()`?

Comment: So, versions it is composition inside class `P`. Is it okay? `class P() {
   constructor(versions: any) { 
       versions.map((data) => new Version(data));
}` Problem is in type `any` in constructor.
}

Comment: That sounds like something that would be better explained in a new question, because I'm not really sure what you're asking in these comments.